# Answer "yes" to terminal on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to clone from Github using Google Colaboratory, the command I'm using is:

```
!git clone git@github.com:CliMT/climt.git
```

But I get the following:

```
Cloning into 'climt'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

But since this is Google Colaboratory, I can't type "yes" to the terminal.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need public-read access you can replace SSH access with https:
!git clone https://github.com/CliMT/climt.git

If you're using SSH because you have plans to write to that github repo from the colaboratory runtime then you'll have to set up SSH keys and probably a known_hosts file manually.
Or script typing "yes" using something like https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

(FTR note the warning isn't colaboratory-specific: https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)

Answer (score 0):

wrong:

```
!git clone git@github.com:CliMT/climt.git
```

In jupyter notebook using :

```
!git clone https://github.com/CliMT/climt.git
```