# how to press enter on Google Colaboratory

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory

I try to install Anaconda on Google Colaboratory but how to press enter on this?
This question is similar [Answer “yes” to terminal on Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709520/answer-yes-to-terminal-on-google-colaboratory)

```
Welcome to Anaconda3 5.1.0
In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
agreement.
Please, press ENTER to continue
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-b` option to run the installer in batch mode.

```
!./miniconda.sh -b
```

It assumes that you agree to all the terms and conditions. But do keep in mind that this doesn't add the installation path to `PATH` variable which you will have manually set if you directly want to use the conda command using:

```
!export PATH=$PATH:<dir_of_conda_installation>/bin
```

Comment: It works, but I think that should use `! bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b` in Colab and how to manually set `path`?  I have tried `export ` but it does not work.

Comment: `bash` and using the `./` are the same thing. And have updated my answer for how to add the path.

Comment: I know, but `./` need root.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by need root ?

Comment: I mean `/bin/sh: 1: ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: That could be possible because of not giving executable permission to the file. That can be done using `chmod +x <filename.sh>`